# In PostgresQL table, how to create column with all values in column1 that ever appear in column2 for an occurrence of that row's column1 value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with the following format:

| Person | Person's Daughter | Person's Mother |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Becky | Sally | Not in list |
| Sally | Libby | Becky |
| Sally | Millie | Becky |
| Libby | Sharon | Sally |
| Millie | N/A | Sally |

I want to write a query that creates a new column, `All of Person's Daughters`, which lists all daughters of the person in that row's `Person` column, like this:

| Person | Person's Daughter | Person's Mother | All of Person's Daughters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Becky | Sally | Not in list | Sally |
| Sally | Libby | Becky | Libby, Millie |
| Sally | Millie | Becky | Libby, Millie |
| Libby | Sharon | Sally | Sharon |
| Millie | N/A | Sally | N/A |

I can't figure it out. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`window functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT 
  *,string_agg(persons_daughter,',') OVER (PARTITION BY person)
FROM t;
```

The query above does exactly what you expect, namely applies the aggregate function `string_agg` over the column `persons_daughter` using `person` as a partition.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3dd3fb55670b79d4c3b9cb31603b7321)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    mother.person, 
    mother.persons_daughter, 
    mother.persons_mother, 
    STRING_AGG(daughter.person, ',') as all_of_persons_daughters
FROM table AS mother
INNER JOIN table AS daughter
    ON mother.person = daughter.persons_mother
GROUP BY mother.person, mother.persons_daughter, mother.persons_mother
```

Comment: How would I modify this if I did not have `Person's Daughter` column?

Comment: I have posted a separate question for the slightly different situation I ask about in the above comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163631/in-postgresql-table-how-to-create-column-with-all-values-in-column1-for-which-t).

Comment: Using t ang t1 although brief can hide the true meening and make your SQL error prone. From your JOIN I can tell the `t` should be called `mother` and `t1` should be called `daughter`.  After that you'll see you are not aggregating daughters into all_of_persons_daughters - its granddaughters actualy :)

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis you're right, I fixed the query