# In PostgresQL table, how to create column with all values in column1 for which the current row's value in column1 appears in column2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with the following format:

| Person | Person's Mother |
| --- | --- |
| Becky | Not in list |
| Sally | Becky |
| Libby | Sally |
| Millie | Sally |
| Sharon | Libby |

I want to write a query that creates a new column, `All of Person's Daughters`, which lists all daughters of the person in that row's `Person` column, like this:

| Person | Person's Mother | All of Person's Daughters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Becky | Not in list | Sally |
| Sally | Becky | Libby, Millie |
| Libby | Sally | Sharon |
| Millie | Sally | N/A |
| Sharon | Libby | N/A |

How can I do this?

Comment: this is a very bad idea.  it is not advisable to denormalize in such a manner.  If you would like to query then investigate LIST AGGEREGATE functions

Comment: Can you explain further? I'm not sure what you mean by denormalizing here. The constraints are imposed upon me by the data I have available, not by choice.

Comment: How is this different than [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163187/in-postgresql-table-how-to-create-column-with-all-values-in-column1-that-ever-a)

Comment: I think it's a different problem give the lack of a `Person's Daughter` column, right? I actually misstated the question there (am essentially analogizing from a more complicated real-life example). I don't actually have a corollary to that column, and the answers seem to rely on it. I left the previous question up for posterity, though, since it is indeed a situation some might encounter. If these questions are actually equivalent, can you help me understand why? I'm a SQL novice and it really melts my brain sometimes.

Comment: @223seneca There was an error in my answer to your other question and I fixed it, so in the end the "Person's daugher" column is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a subquery where you apply `string_agg()` over `person` for each `persons_mother`:

```
SELECT person,persons_mother,
  coalesce((SELECT string_agg(t2.person,',') 
            FROM t t2 
            WHERE t1.person = t2.persons_mother),'N/A')
FROM t t1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=390d8fa8225beb574737190714b117d1)

```
CREATE TABLE t (person text, persons_mother text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('Becky','Not in list'),
('Sally','Becky'),
('Libby','Sally'),
('Millie','Sally'),
('Sharon','Libby');


SELECT person,persons_mother,
  COALESCE((SELECT string_agg(t2.person,',') 
   FROM t t2 
   WHERE t1.person = t2.persons_mother),'N/A')
FROM t t1;

 person | persons_mother |   coalesce   
--------+----------------+--------------
 Becky  | Not in list    | Sally
 Sally  | Becky          | Libby,Millie
 Libby  | Sally          | Sharon
 Millie | Sally          | N/A
 Sharon | Libby          | N/A
```

Comment: This is the one that worked best for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this ([Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cFUbbTAXJpLxdJRjq1r38Q/0))

```
select m.*, string_agg(d.name,',') as "person's mother"
from person m left outer join person d on m.name = d.mother
group by m.name,m.mother
```